# turn off wifi in Android Q

Tags: android

Is there any way besides the standard *ConnectivityManager*-API to modify wifi state in android q? I've just read google removed the api in android 10. Im willing to give the app android device administrator status, grant all permissions with adb, etc as I wont publish the app and will only use it for myself.

Comment: Definitely you are doing something fishy :)

Answer (score 2):

Your app must be a device owner as a variant to use `wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false)` method that is deprecated started from Q.

Deprecation Exemptions:
Device Owner (DO), Profile Owner (PO) and system apps.
[WifiManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code to disable wifi :

```
 try {
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            return wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
```

to disconnect wifi :

```
 WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
 wifiManager.disconnect();
```

and the following code to forget a particular wifi network :

```
 try {
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            List wifiNetworks = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
            for (Object wifiConf : wifiNetworks) {
                if (((WifiConfiguration) wifiConf).SSID.equalsIgnoreCase(SSID)) {
                    return wifiManager.removeNetwork(wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getNetworkId()) && wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```